# Symfony 3 - Add an array entities to the database from entity?

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, collections, roles

I would like to add a field of type array to my database, and be able to use it, as does FOSUserBundle with the roles.

The goal is to add a table of packages to my User entity.

I don't want a join table.

I reproduced the same schema as for the roles and I added all this to my User entity

**Some code of my User.php entity :**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
/**
     * @var array
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="packages", type="array", length=255)
     */
    private $packages;


    public function addPackage($package)
    {
        if (!in_array($package, $this->packages, true)) {
            $this->packages[] = $package;
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPackages()
    {
        return $this->packages;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setPackages(array $packages)
    {
        $this->packages = array();

        foreach ($packages as $package) {
            $this->addPackage($package);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function removePackage($package)
    {
        if (false !== $key = array_search(strtoupper($package), $this->packages, true)) {
            unset($this->packages[$key]);
            $this->packages = array_values($this->packages);
        }

        return $this;
    }

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->packages = array();
}
```

In my database, the packages field is present, and seems to be like the roles field. But when I connect with my user on the site, I have this error:

> Could not convert database value "" to Doctrine Type array

Someone would know what's wrong with the code?

My Database screenshot :

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb8mF.png)
[Database view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1X8e.png)

Comment: How big is the array you're trying to save. What type is the column in the database and length? The array type converts an array into a string representation, so you may be losing data when inserting into the DB?

Comment: The length of my array seems be of 255. Type : longtext.
Everything is like for roles.
I edit my post to add 2 screenshots to show you

Comment: Personally, I'd try and change the DB column type to TEXT and see what happens.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought too, I tried, but doing this, I get an error when I try to add something to my packages attribute: Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Comment: I edited my comment to say the Database Column type, not the doctrine type.

Comment: Oh okay! So by simply changing the type to TEXT in the database, nothing changes, I always have this error : Could not convert database value "" to Doctrine Type array

It's amazing that it does not work when I take the same pattern as for roles

Comment: We agree that my array "packages" must contain package entities (id, title, etc ...). It's the same thing, does not it?

Comment: Wait, packages are doctrine entities? Then you should probably be using a doctrine relationship / join annotation, not storing an string representation.

Comment: Yes, they are elements of doctrine. So I wanted to do that yes, with a relationship ManyToMany, which would create a new table. The problem is that being a beginner, I do not really know how to get out after to feed the table, because there is no repository for the new table

Comment: That's definitely the way you should be going making the current question an XY problem that can probably be closed. I don't really understand from your comment what issues you had with ManyToMany, so I'd suggest reading the docs again to see the examples, try them, and if / when it fails, perhaps ask a new question specific to that that.

Comment: Could it be that you created a user with no packages or existing users with no packages? Maybe you should always instantiate the class variable with an array, i.e. `private $packages = [];` edit: I noticed that at the bottom you do this with the constructor, so never mind. Still in your database the field seems to be empty. Are those existing users or did they already have that field? You should investigate why the database value seems to be an empty string instead of a serialized array like in roles.

Comment: It's okay, I managed to do what I wanted, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set type="string" in your $packages, you can keep the "array" and do this sql command, and add nullable=true for the other values that you already have in your BD: Like this, the empty values will be converted to null.

```
 @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
```

and do sql command:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD my_new_column LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)'
```

or by symfony console:

```
php bin/console doctrine:query:sql "UPDATE <<your_table_name>> SET <<field_name>> = NULL WHERE <<field_name>>=''"
```

Comment: nice!! glad to help!